# how to generate random string of given language / locale

Tags: java, string, random

I need to generate random String as output,
Input can be language name / locale name which are already installed in System.

All suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks.

*Taken from comment*

method signature can be like:

```
public String getRandomStringOfLocale(Locale locale);
```

so for `input=Locale.ENGLISH` output can be `="adsaswzxcvnaj"` (random) like wise for any locale.

Comment: So the string should not really be random? How exactly should it depend on the locale? Could you give examples?

Comment: method signature can be like:
public String getRandomStringOfLocale(Locale locale); 
so for input=Locale.ENGLISH  output can be="adsaswzxcvnaj" (random) 
like wise for any locale.

Comment: @SmartSolution - still don't get it. It looks like an encryption/decryption or hashing problem rather. Please *edit your question* and add a reason **why** you want to create a random and **what** you want to do with it (this really would help to find a *smart solution* ;))

Comment: Might this be for testing where you need to test with different locale to see if chars are mangled?

Comment: Uhm ... giving a single example is kind of useless. What do you expect the output to be for `de_DE`? `ru_RU`? `ar_SA`? `ja_JP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be after is that you want random characters from one particular Unicode code block or another. Is that right? I don't think Android ships with any definitions of the code blocks exposed in the API. (There must be some definition for the Character.UnicodeBlock methods to work, but I think it's inaccessible.)

You can probably produce your own table of Unicode character ranges, then work out how to match one up when given a locale. Lots of locales will map to the same Unicode block, however. For instance, most Latin-1 languages (English, Spanish, French, German, ...) will map to the BASIC_LATIN block.

If you want random strings that can, say, include ñ for a Spanish locale but not for an English locale, that's a lot tougher.

Answer (score 5):

This may sound weird but can solve your problem.

Grab a random article from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org) in the language and characters set that you need to have a random string. Remove all non alphanumeric characters and HTML tags. Instantiate a random integer number generator and use it to pick characters from the string representing the text.

```
String text = WikipediaGrabber.grab(Locale.FRENCH);
text = removeNonAlphaNumericCharacters(text);
Random r = new Random();
StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CHARACTERS_PER_RANDOM_STRING; i++)
{
  int index = r.nextInt() * text.length();
  word.append(text.substring(index, index+1);
}
System.out.println("random string in French: " + word.toString());
```

Comment: +1, we used wikipedia to get Russian, French and AXIS-OF-EVIL(TM)-language text to test the IO-behavior of our application.